# C++/PHP capture what called the executable

Tags: php, c++, parameter-passing, executable

Is there no way to capture what opened an exe? I'm using exec in php, the executable returns values for the rest of my php. However, I would like c++ to know what php file initiated it without having to send the path as a vairable.

This will be a local php file, and I want to control what the exe does based on the metadata of the calling php.

php:

```
$CMD = "/program.exe";
exec($CMD, $ret);
echo $ret[0];
```

cpp:

```
int main(){
  if (PHP-METADATA-OF-CALLING-FILE == VALID PARAMTER{
    cout << "valid php" << endl;
  }else{
    cout << "invalid php" << end;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Might seem odd, but the goal is to ensure a user cannot modify or use custom php against the exe. So I'd like the exe to know exactly what called it.

Comment: No. You can get the parent process id by walking the process list, but then you may have to run with elevated privileges, and still wouldn't tell you which PHP file. Better to find another security method

Comment: for example, you could pass the php file path and a hashed version of the path. Then, any rogue script would need to know your hashing algorithm to succeed. But also...if users can make custom PHP and run it, you are already compromised